# Derive conditions on features from clustering

Tags: clustering

I have this problem: I do cluster a dataset with all numeric features.
I want to derive from the generated clusters a set of conditions against the features in order to quickly classify new data into one or another cluster.

For example, let's say my dataset is

```
(id),feature1,feature2,feature3
(1), 1,100,20
(2), 1,110,50
(3), 1,110,600
...
```

I generate two clusters and get:

```
cluster1 -> 1,2,...
cluster2 -> 3,...
```

I want to obtain some conditions to implement this whenever a new sample arrive:

```
if feature1 == 1 and feature2 == 110 
then 
    cluster1
else 
    cluster2
```

Bonus points if I can do it in weka.

Answer (score 0):

Clustering isn't classification.

If you want a classifier, then train a classifier.

E.g. feed your clustering into a **decision tree**, and you will get an easy to understand method to classify your new observations, similar to the rules you asked for.